# How to test if a line is empty?

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, getline

I'm actually trying to understand how does the `getline()` function works!  But I'm facing difficulties to test if a line is empty or not!

Here is my code:

```
ifstream fichier("upload.txt",ios::binary);
string ligne;
while(getline(fichier,ligne))
{
    cout<<ligne<<endl;
    if(ligne=="")
         cout<<"line below is empty"<<endl;         
}
```

But, the if-condition seems to be not working :((

Comment: Aside:: use `empty()` function of `std::string`.

Comment: I think it's probably opening the file in binary mode that's the problem, try taking that out.

Comment: `if ( ligne == "")` will work as long as the liine has no other whitespace characters. If it has spaces or tabs, then it won't work.

Comment: This is not a C question. Do not add the `c` tag.

Comment: @RSahu same with the `empty()` method

Comment: @RemyLebeau, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, a line break is normally CRLF (`0x0D 0x0A`). `std::getline()` will read until it encounters the LF and discard it from the returned `std::string`. If the `std::ifstream` is opened in text mode (the default mode), platform line breaks are normalized to LF and a leading CR will    also be discarded. But, if opened in binary mode, the CR will not be discarded. So you will have to check for that:

```cpp
ifstream fichier("upload.txt", ios::binary);
string ligne;
while (getline(fichier, ligne)) {
    if (ligne.empty() || ligne == "\r") {
        cout << "line is empty" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << ligne << endl;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, don't use binary mode for text files:

```cpp
ifstream fichier("upload.txt");
string ligne;
while (getline(fichier, ligne)) {
    if (ligne.empty()) {
        cout << "line is empty" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << ligne << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is opening file in binary. Other than that, you should do few things :

1. Check if file is properly opened
2. Compare against empty()
3. Check if string only contains space , then it's considered empty.
4. Close file

   ```
   ifstream fichier("upload.txt", std::ifstream::in ); //File opened for reading.
   string ligne;
   //Always Check if file is properly opened.
   if (fichier.is_open() ) 
   {
      while(getline(fichier,ligne))
      {
         cout<<ligne<<endl;
          if(ligne.empty() || str.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos)
           cout<<"line below is empty"<<endl;         
      }
      fichier.close();

   }
   else 
   {
    // show message:
     std::cout << "Error opening file";
   }
   ```